# Calling a non static method in a static testfile

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am writing a 3 part program with a superclass(GeometricObject1) and a subclass(Triangle).  The last part is the test file which needs to call the three methods from the subclass and two from the super class and then call the toString method from the super class. Here is my code for the test file:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class testTriangle here.
 * 
 * @author Sophia 
 * @version 
 */
public class testTriangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       Triangle nTriangle = new Triangle();
       GeometricObject1 go1 = new GeometricObject1();

       nTriangle.setside1( 1.0 );
       nTriangle.setside2( 1.5 );
       nTriangle.setside3( 1.0 );
       go1.setColor( "yellow" );
       go1.setFilled( true );

   /*Triangle.setside1( 1.0 );
   Triangle.setside2( 1.5 );
   Triangle.setside3( 1.0 );
   super.setColor( "yellow" );
   super.setFilled( true );
   */


   System.out.println( go1.toString() );
}
}
```

Can you use nTriangle to call public methods from both the superclass or subclass? If so is it better to use nTriangle to call methods from the superclass and the subclass? Or better to leave it as is?

If there is a toString method in both the superclass and the subclass will replacing go1.toString with nTriangle.goString in the line

```
System.out.println( go1.toString() );
```

call the toString from the superclass or the subclass?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Calling go1.setColor and go1.setFilled will not affect nTriangle.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

`nTriangle` and `go1` are 2 different instances (you are creating 2 instances with the `new` keyword). So modifications you are applying to `go1` are not effective for `nTriangle`. You should call the `setColor()` and `setFilled()` methods from the instance you want to modify, that is the `nTriangle` instance.

You can also call the `toString()` method automatically from inside the `println()` method:

```
System.out.println( nTriangle );
```

If you override the `toString()` method in both the `GeometricObject1` and the `Triangle` classes, then you'll use the `Triangle` version if the instance is a `Triangle` and the `GeometricObject1` version if your instance is a `GeometricObject1`. Inside of the `toString()` method of the `Triangle` class, you can call the `GeometricObject1 toString()` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " - Triangle version.";
}
```

Comment: If there was a toString method in the superclass and the subclass would I still use nTriangle to call the toString from the superclass only?

Comment: Thank you it was helpful. Just one last question.  THe superclass and the subclass have different things written in their toString methods. would it still be done the same way?

Answer (score 1):

> Because the subclass inherits all public methods from the superclass
>   should I get rid of the line

If you are not overriding the superclass methods `setColor()` and `setFilled()` and `toString()` within `GeometricObject1` then YES you can get rid of that line

Answer (score 1):

Yes you probably should.

However you may want to also have a `testGeometricObject1` class which is designed to test the  `GeometricObject1` class alone (including methods `setColor` and `setFilled`).

For instance `Triangle.setColor` and `GeometricObject1.setColor` may not have the same implementation (you can always override the behaviour in the subclass), so you want to test both potential implementations.